# Firebase Storage connection with HTML and TypeScript WITHOUT Angular or React Possible on Intellij?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, firebase

My goal for the project portion is to be able to have a functioning login and register page using TypeScript.

Currently my code works without a database, but I wanted to use Firebase to register user's usernames and passwords, so they can login with ease.

The only tutorial I have found only use Firebase with Angular or React, and I was wondering if there was a way to use Firebase storage without it?

The IDE I am using is Intellij.

if needed here is my registering page code:

> .ts code:

```
class RegisterTs{
    username: string;
    password: string;
    password2:string;

    constructor(username: string, password: string, password2:string ) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.password2 = password2;


        let registerBtn = document.getElementById("enterR")
        registerBtn.addEventListener("click", (e: Event) => {
            return RegisterTs.validateInput(this.password,this.password2)
        });


        let forgotBtn= document.getElementById("forgotPass")
        forgotBtn.addEventListener("click",(e:Event) =>RegisterTs.forgotPasswordR());
    }



    private static validateInput(password: string, password2:string) {
        if(password==password2){
            return alert("success")
        }
        else{
            return alert("Password inputs do not match")
        }
    }

    private static forgotPasswordR() {
        return alert("tough luck lmao")
    }
}




window.onload= function() {
    let iUser =(document.getElementById("re") as HTMLInputElement).value;
    let iPass =(document.getElementById("rp") as HTMLInputElement).value;
    let iPass2 =(document.getElementById("rrp") as HTMLInputElement).value;
    let regTs = new RegisterTs(iUser,iPass,iPass2);
}
```

> .html code

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
  <TITLE>Capstone Typescript Login</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>

<header>
  <h2>Billy Bronco's Grading Calculator</h2>
</header>

<div id="container">

  <div id="tabs">

    <p id="rt" class="tabs" >Register</p>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Login.css">

    <div id="clear"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="cont">

    <div id="register" class="comm">
      <h3>Register</h3>

      <input id="re" type="email" placeholder="Email" required/>
      <input id="rp" type="password" placeholder="Password" required/>
      <input id="rrp" type="password" placeholder="Re write Password" required/>

      <input type="button" class="button" id="enterR" value="Register">
      <input type="button" class="button" id="forgotPass" value="Forgot Password?">
      <a href="login_view.html" > Already have an account? CLICK HERE </a>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
<script src="RegisterTs.js"></script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

> Thank You!

Comment: let me get this clear, you want to use firebase to basically register users right? and you are just using basic HTML/CSS/js right? no react or angular

Comment: @Abhishek Yes! thats the goal of it! I will be using firebase in other parts of my project, but I wasn't sure if there is a way to do it without Angular or React, which I would prefer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth). you shouldn't use firebase storage as its designed to store larger files than strings like files such as a word document or a video file etc.

Firebase comes with authentication system of its own which allows you to authenticate a user without needing to match password and username individually, like you are doing, that is considered worst practice as it exposes the actual password and username. That is why storing the password/username inside Firebase Realtime Database or Firestore is also a bad idea.

There is no requirement to use React or angular to use Firebase Auth. you can simple do all the js steps said in the tutorial and you will have yourself a working authentication platform. Since you know typescript, using and reading normal javascript shouldn't be a problem.

[Follow this guide from Firebase here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#web-v8) to understand how to add a user authentication system using email and password. You will not need most of the code you have written above.